# How to create tab url

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, tabs, reload

This my tab. I want when page reload open second tab. How can I do that

**HTML**

```
<li role="presentation" class="active">
 <a href="#details" aria-controls="details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details</a>
</li>
 <li role="presentation">
<a href="#comments" aria-controls="comments" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Comments: (<?php echo $comments_count[0]->total?>)</a>
</li>
```

I am found this jQuery code but its not working:

```
// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this bit of code

> Html file

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">messages</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">settings</div>
</div>
```

> Javascript part

```
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

// store the currently selected tab in the hash value
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
  var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
  window.location.hash = id;
});

// on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('#myTab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: I am used this url for reload. Its go to the message tab but page not reloading.    `success:function(data){
 window.location.href = "http://localhost/demo/item-details/?id=19#messages";`
},